# Hibernate - Double left join to same table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm having two tables

First **plan_time**

```
NAME | START_FK | END_FK 
------------------------
test | 1        | 2
```

start_fk and end_fk are FK refering to table **times** :

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | time1
2  | time2
```

I'm executing simple select query:

```
SELECT pt.*, t1.*, t2.* FROM plan_table pt LEFT JOIN times t1 ON t1.id = pt.start_fk LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t2.id = pt.end_fk
```

And here is the problem. Under sql console I'm getting good result:

```
First row from plan_table join by first row from times table and second row from times table.
```

When I'm doing that via hibernate

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = s.createSQLQuery( SQL-QUERY )
            .addEntity(PlanTime.class)
            .addEntity(Times.class)
            .addEntity(Times.class);
```

I'm getting 3 objects

1. first row from plan_table
2. first row from times table
3. **first row from times table** - this is duplication of second object.

It have to be something with Hibernate... I checked SQL which is send to DB and it is ok.

:/

Please help.

Comment: why don't use hql instead of sql query? use this  `.addEntity("t2", Times.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for this problem. Here are tips which helped me:

1. I'm receiving t1 and t2 form PlanTable object via **getStartFk()** and **getEndFk()** methods.
2. I'm using **eager fetching**

I'm still trying to find out what is status of this issue.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3988